# Is mathematics a mental idea?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is mathematics a mental idea?

According to [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65788/33165) answer, a mental idea cannot exist without a mind.

If mathematics is a mental idea, what does this imply about the laws of physics which can be modeled mathematically? Is there a way to fully explain this without resorting to a conscious mind behind them (either within us or perhaps outside us)?

Comment: Mathematics is a human activity, a language, a practice.

Comment: What does it mean "mathematics itself" ? Do you suggest that there is also a mathematics that "other from" mathematics ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but is math a mental idea?

Comment: Kant thought so (more or less), according to him it means that we discover laws of physics because our minds ("understanding") organize our experience according to those laws in the first place:"*If he is to know anything 
with a priori certainty he must not ascribe to the figure any
thing save what necessarily follows from what he has himself set into it in accordance with his concept.*"

Comment: Everything object is an idea and if it weren't we wouldn't know about it. The question is whether some ideas represent objects that are independent of mind. The mental status of mathematics allows us to speculate there are no such objects but does not rule out the possibility. If it did then all philosophers would be idealists of some sort.

Comment: Chartres can be modeled by Pla-Doh.  Does that mean it did not exist until they invented it?  All models and explanation of something come after the thing itself.  So physics comes after mathematics and mathematics comes after the universe.  Physics does not cause the physical world to behave in a predictable fashion.  It describes the behavior.

Comment: "Idea" is a very philosophically loaded term, and has been employed by many philosophers to mean very specific, technical things which are totally different from what most people mean by that word. This makes the question difficult to answer. The statement "a mental idea cannot exist without a mind," also depends on the definition of "idea", but my guess is that any reasonable definition would make it tautological.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to mathematics as a mental idea is intuitionism.  Here is Rosalie Iemhoff's description of it:

> Intuitionism is based on the idea that mathematics is a creation of the mind. The truth of a mathematical statement can only be conceived via a mental construction that proves it to be true, and the communication between mathematicians only serves as a means to create the same mental process in different minds.

Here are the questions:

> If math is a mental idea, what does this imply about the laws of physics which can be modeled mathematically? Is there a way to fully explain this without resorting to a conscious mind behind them (either within us or more likely, outside us)?

It is unlikely that one can fully explain anything. One offers the best explanation one can and then one remains open to evidence countering the explanation. There may be a conscious mind behind everything. This would be a form of [panpsychism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panpsychism), [pantheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism) or [theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theism).

Given that mathematics, from an intuitionistic perspective, is a mental idea it does not mean that whatever the laws of physics are supposed to refer to is not actually out there, but it does suggest that the mathematical formulations of those laws are also mental ideas communicated between physicists which can be falsified with new evidence.

---

Iemhoff, Rosalie, "Intuitionism in the Philosophy of Mathematics", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2019 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2019/entries/intuitionism/.

Comment: Inside, outside, and containment in general is a conceptual metaphor, and might be misleading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor

Comment: This is not really the distinction.  Platonism and various other idealisms also depict mathematics as generated by the mind, or at least as part of it, but they put the mind at the root of reality.  Intuitionism admits that mind is uniquely *human* (or animal), and not that of God or some other underlying mental reality.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematics is language. All languages exist on verbal levels of our intellect.

Laws of physics exist independantly of mathematics or any other form of language. Laws of physics are observable and can be expressed mathematically.

---

EDIT 16, october 2019.

Mathematics, like any language, is a system of concepts and relationships between them. All concepts exist on a mental level.

For example, you can clearly perceive with your eyes the size of two circles on the [picture](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/72400/72480/72480_circles_lg.gif). Your eyes see the size of circles directly, even before you express it in numbers (by using some mathematical tool).

The physical laws can be described very accurately with mathematics. However, direct perception is more advanced than the language. You can clearly see the physical phenomenon without the need for any descriptions. The conclusion is that knowledge comes from direct perception.

Comment: how does this answer the question? thanks

Comment: It depends on whether by 'laws of physics' you are citing the symbol "laws of physics" or the referent, laws of physics. :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Meaning

Comment: I'm refering to what we call "the laws of physics". The referent or the observable phenomena of material world. Not the map, but the theritory.

Comment: Mathematics is not language. This is at best an analogy.

Comment: @M.leFou — I'd reconsider that, if I were you. Mathematics is clearly a system of symbolic representation, which means that it is (at least in part) a language.

Comment: @TedWrigley On that definition of language you include a lot of things (such as mathematics) that I'd wager most people would not expect. For example, if I draw you two scribbles and declare the one represents hats and the other represents cars - is this a "system of symbolic representation"? Then I have just created a language!

Comment: @TedWrigley The point is, what people mean when they say "language" is actually quite specific. Its a complex system exhibiting very interesting (and well studied) features such as recursivity and complex grammatical structures. Now you can say mathematics is a language, that's fine - its kind of like how a painter might say she "speaks the language of art" to refer to the way that colours and figures have a kind of culturally-encoded meaning. This is merely an analogy.

Comment: @M.leFou — Give any definition of language that you like, and mathematics will fit it. I'm not particularly concerned by what ordinary people mean when they use a word, because ordinary people use terms loosely and inconsistently.

Comment: @TedWrigley Well thats fine to not be concerned with the actual use of the word "language". But I'd consider it kind of sloppy to re-use the term in whatever technical sense you have in mind. Better to come up with your own to avoid confusion. As for "any definition", I gave one in my previous comment (the standard definition that any linguist will give - a complex recursive computational system with certain features including grammar). Since mathematics is expressed through (what ordinary people call) a language (usually English) you have some higher, "meta" concept in mind.

Comment: Ta, you don't understand. Part of thinking philosophically is being both precise and consistent, yet you want to use a definition loosely in order to produce an inconsistent result. Are you seriously suggesting that mathematics is *not* "a complex recursive computational system with certain features including grammar"? The fact that people talk about mathematics in English is irrelevant: People talk about *Spanish* in English; that doesn't make Spanish 'meta'.

Comment: @TedWrigley Indeed they do, but would you say that "talking about Spanish" is a language? It would be a strange use of the term, right? "Talking about Spanish" is something you do through language, but this doesn't make it a language in itself. I think the same is true of mathematics. I'm curious: you seem to be suggesting that mathematics has a grammar - can you describe it?

Comment: A grammar is "the system and structure of a language". So let's look at these two 'phrases': "2+2=4" and "2=+4 2". You recognize (I expect) that the first is a valid mathematical statement while the second is not. That tells me that you understand the grammar of arithmetic. Mathematics has clear rules for how one can put together mathematical statements. It has rules for carrying on 'discussions' (developing a mathematical 'phrase' across multiple statements). That is a grammar.

Comment: Ok, so even if we concede that the symbols used to express equations involving e.g. 2-ary infix operators is a language, you still have a ways to go before arriving at your claim. You need to say that mathematics consists of exactly such equations. Needless to say this would be quite a jaundiced view of contemporary mathematics (or even ancient mathematics for that matter) which comprises among other things homological algebra, the Langlands program and the proof of Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Lovely question Michael.

If that @RodolfoAP answer is literally exactly true,

- science is based on math
- math is based on perceiving mind
- my perception (mind) is all = solipsism

Since all modern life is science-based solipsism is the ultimate philosophy.

As a secondary proof of

> Anything is true if we will it strongly enough (The Secret!) 
>   consider:

1. That answer is the highest voted atm
2. That answer is the wrongest in that it directly contradicts one of the cornerstones of 20th century logic — [Tarski's undefinability of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)
   ([subsumes Godel incompleteness](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/470/37256) )

And if you don't take the *math-defines-truth* bit too literally and only focus on "It's an ill-formed question" (others there like @celtschk do it in more detail in other answers),
this may not give quite as egregious results as *math-defines-truth* but it is still nonsense as @conifold points out in
[funny contradictions of LPists/analytic philosophers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/64190/37256)

Personally I find the next most-voted answer by @JD more insidiously dangerous than RodolfoAP's. 
I won't explain that further than to state without more "proof"

- I am a – maybe unwilling – platonist
- Plato would be mighty offended with 20th century (cantorean/hilbertean) "platonism"

The best answer to this was given by @Jobermark explanation and defence of intuitionism. Perhaps [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/64039/37256).
Seems to be deleted!

Comment: I have no idea what this means.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Nor do I about your comment. The difference is that my answer has a dozen paras a couple dozen sentences. Your comment has just one!

Comment: Would it help @nielsnielsen if I said that extremity of math-is-analytic (RodolfoAP) as well as extremity of the other side : msth-is-synthetic (JD answer) produce nonsensical results?

Comment: is that teh only option though. could there be a higher mind over everything as max planck thought?

Comment: no, it would not help. I think I'm done here.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications.+1

Comment: I think that's the point of my answer @michael. Viz that the two extremities are most unacceptable *doesn't imply* that the spectrum inbetween is unworthy of exploration.

Answer (score 0):

*Long comment*

*Idea* is a complex philosophical term.

According to [Descartes’ Theory of Ideas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-ideas/)

> the mind is an existing substance, and thought or thinking is its attribute. An idea is a mode of thinking. In being a mode of thinking, an idea is understood as a way of being (an instance of) thinking, or an idea is way in which an instance of thinking is manifested. This is similar to what Descartes says about a body : [t]he nature of a body is to be extended (in length, breadth, and depth). A body is a substance, and extension is its attribute.
>
> ideas are cast as modes of thinking that represent (or present or exhibit) objects to the mind — objects such as a man, or Pegasus, or the sky, or an angel, or God. [...] Descartes is careful to not identify ideas as *pictures* or as *visual images*, but instead says that they are as it were images of things.

Descartes' point of view can be compared with modern concept of [Mental Representation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mental-representation/) :

> [this theory] takes as its starting point commonsense mental states, such as thoughts, beliefs, desires, perceptions and imagings. Such states are said to ave “intentionality” — they are *about* or *refer* to things.

Is this what yo mean ?

Maybe your are referring to mathematical *concepts*, like e.g. that of *number* or *set*. In this case, the question will be : the concept (idea) of *number* is an idea (representation) of what ?

Or instead are you alluding to a "subjective" approach to mathematical concepts ? In this case, they are *construction* of human mind (see [Kant's theory of the construction of mathematical concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mathematics/#KanCriMat) and [Brouwer's Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/#Bri).

*More details are needed* in order to go on with the discussion...

Comment: i just find it curious that the laws of physics can be modeled mathematically. doesnt that imply some sort of mind behind them as explained in the question

Comment: @Michael - as per many many posts on this site, the question is not "curious" : it is a philosophical problem unsolved since (at least) Plato. Many many different views have been proposed and discussed; in a nutshell, the "big divide" is : if math is discovered, how we "perceive"/learn abstract entities like numbers and sets ? If math is invented by human mind (like e.g. chess game) how is it possible that it "works" so well ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is mathematics a mental idea?

Mathematics is an [abstraction](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=abstraction), an idea, a thought, a meaning and is not physical.

> According to this answer, a mental idea cannot exist without a mind.

It depends on who you ask. Descartes would disagree with his [dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism#Substance_or_Cartesian_dualism). [Daniel Dennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Dennett) would disagree with Descartes. Theology still tends towards dualism since it preserves [supernaturalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural), while [cognitive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science) largely rejects it.

> If mathematics is a mental idea, what does this imply about the laws of physics which can be modeled mathematically? Is there a way to fully explain this without resorting to a conscious mind behind them (either within us or more likely, outside us)?

It implies that [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) generates meaningful expressions in mathematics and science and uses linguistic elements like syntax and orthography to describe, explain, and predict physical phenomena. Consciousness seems to be required for theory generation. Ever read a theory determined and expressed by an unconscious mind?

These are generally accepted ideas among contemporary philosophers of mind. Where they disagree is on meaning, terminology, and methods when confronting problems like the [hard problem of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness).

This evokes metaphysical positions such as [naive realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism), [transcendental idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?sort=relevance&search=Transcendental%20idealism&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1), and [philosophical realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_realism), etc.

---

EDIT 2019-09-24

> If mathematics is a mental idea, what does this imply about the laws of physics which can be modeled mathematically? Is there a way to fully explain this without resorting to a conscious mind behind them (either within us or perhaps outside us)?

It depends on your metaphysical presupposition. If you believe in [physicalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism) for instance, especially a non-reductive form, you according to [Jaegwon Kim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaegwon_Kim), you accept three principles at a minimum:

1. The mental [supervenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaegwon_Kim) on the physical.
2. The [mind-body duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism) is a [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake).
3. The mental is wholly [dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) and characterized by the physical.

(See Ch.1, *Philosophy of the Mind*)

As such, the "laws of physics" is both a symbol that  [given the triangle of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_reference) refers to patterns in observation of phenomena that correspond with patterns in [noumena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon), and [das Ding an sich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing-in-itself) presuming a dichotomy between the observer and the external universe.

Comment: what does dualism have to do with whether an idea can exist without a mind?

Comment: @michael I'm not a dualist, so maybe I misunderstand the position. I guess I would say that Cartesian duality has a distinction between the body and the mind, but if one can divorce the body from the mind, one can divorce ideas from mind along the lines of Platonic thinking. If the mind supervenes on the body, then ideas necessarily must be tied to the mind?

Comment: @michael I updated my answer to better answer your question

Answer (score 0):

This is a knotty problem and there are many different perspectives on it but I would recommend looking at the details.

You might need a mind to discover the laws of physics and program a computer to simulate them. But when it's running it just carries on by itself and does not require any mental intervention. So there's nothing here to imply that the universe needs a mind in order to exist or go about its business.

It might require minds to make sense of it (but we already knew that).

You can make a case that math is "all in the mind" but if so it would be unusual to think that it was necessary for physics (but maybe necessary for some kind of human understanding of it).

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy, and thanks for contributing with a question/response! If you haven't done so, please take a quick moment to take the tour. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour More specifics can be found in the help center. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: "But when it's running it just carries on by itself and does not require any mental intervention" - anything to back this?

Comment: I've written physical simulations on computers before and they ran fine when I turned my back on them. This is all I'm claiming. For all I know the actual universe does require the constant oversight of a conscious deity but we haven't established that with this particular argument.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like I repeat this point a lot, but so be it...

The mind makes models of the universe in order to explain its own perceptions. Mathematics is one of those models.

If we go down right to the root of mathematics — the concept of 'number' — we can see that 'number' is intimately tied to the concept of 'object'. 'Objects' are things that we count and measure using 'numbers'; 'number' has no meaning outside the context of independent and delimited 'objects'. That's why we do not *count* things like water, air, or electricity: there is no natural object-boundary within these things that sets up individual items to be counted. But philosophically speaking, the concept of 'object' is imposed on the world by the mind according to various characteristics that we perceive to be relevant. It's a *good* model, but part of the reason it's a good model is that we are fluid in its application.  For instance, if we have five diamonds, we expect that number to remain constant — e.g., we would be surprised if we turned around and suddenly discovered there were six diamonds — but if we split one of the diamonds we don't bat an eye about the fact that five suddenly became six. Likewise, if we have five sheep, we expect that one day we will turn around and have more sheep (five becomes seven or eight in the springtime). 'Sheep objects' are numerically fluid, 'diamond objects' are not (except when they are).

I'm fond of Marino Klisovich's answer as well (that mathematics is a language), but mostly through Wittgenstein's understanding of language, which points back at models in the sense I'm talking about.